BBEdit 15 not finding Grep Patterns.xml
Prior BBEdit versions used to have all grep saved patterns written to a Grep Patterns.xml file located in Application Support > BBEdit > Setup > Grep Patterns.xml. However, after the recent upgrade to BBEdit 15 when I click the dropdown for grep patterns my built out file is not detected.
Examining the directory noticed in their Read Me.txt file still calls out to include the file in Setup directory:

This folder contains configuration data for items managed in the Setup window: Grep patterns, file filters, FTP/SFTP bookmarks, and saved search sets for the Multi-File Search window.

but after a reboot the file is still not detected. In BBEdit 15 how can I detect old grep patterns I've saved throughout the years?
